# How To Construct An XPATH With Condition Matching A Preceding Sibling's Child

Tags: html, css, xpath

I need to select the element `<a>` only if the preceding `<li>`'s text value is *LINE 2*

```
    <html>
 <div>
  <label>LABEL 1</label>
   <div>
    <ul>
     <li>LINE ITEM 1</li>
    </ul>
   </div>
   <div>
     <div>
       <a>Edit</a>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
 <div>
  <label>LABEL 2</label>
   <div>
    <ul>
     <li>LINE ITEM 2</li>
    </ul>
   </div>
   <div>
     <div>
       <a>Edit</a>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</html>
```

In the above HTML document, the actual number of  can vary based on design changes, what remains a constant are the values of the line items `<li>`

I want an XPATH query which will fetch the *Edit* immediately following the line item whose value is *LINE ITEM 2*

I have tried some of the suggestions given below but I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this XPATH-expression

```
//ul[li="LINE 2"]/following-sibling::div/a
```

In case you don't know on which level `li` located you can use

```
//li[.="LINE ITEM 2"]/following::a[.="Edit"]
```

Comment: thank you for responding, I've modified my question to reflect exactly what issue I'm facing.

Comment: @DhiwakarRavikumar , my second suggestion should work. It will fetch the first occurrence of link with text "Edit" preceded by `li` with text "LINE 2"

Comment: It works but the only problem is if I were to search for LINE ITEM 1, it returns both hyperlinks, I only need the next immediately occurring Edit. Is there anyway to achieve this without restoring to Indexing ?

Comment: This uses indexing, there is no way to directly get it without using Indexing i.e. without the [1] ?

Comment: @DhiwakarRavikumar specifying index `[1]` is the easiest way to fetch immediate next node. I guess it can be done without index, but that expression will looks much more complicated

Comment: @DhiwakarRavikumar `//li[.="LINE ITEM 1"]/ancestor::*[count(.//a[.="Edit"])=1]//a[.="Edit"]` This is one of options but, as I said, it looks not good :)

Comment: thanks, I can work with this, out of curiosity, is there a way to fetch the Edit directly only if the preceding line item's value is LINE ITEM 2  ? In that case, only 1 anchor link would be selected, correct ?

Comment: @DhiwakarRavikumar did you mean `//a[. = "Edit" and ./preceding::li[.="LINE ITEM 2"]]`? Yes, in this case only one, but in case `"LINE ITEM 1"` - again we'll fetch both Edit buttons

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this and see if it works:

```
//a[ancestor::div[.//ul/text()="LINE 2"]]
```

Edit:

```
//a[text()="Edit"][ancestor::div[.//li[text()="LINE ITEM 2"]]]
```

Comment: thank you for responding, I've modified my question to reflect exactly what issue I'm facing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this maybe:

```
a[ancestor::div/preceding-sibling::ul/descendant::li[normalize-space(text())='LINE 2']]
```

Not sure of the structure of you want in terms of elements though.